# Simple Guitar Tone Adjustments

Tags: passive-filter

What passive-type tone adjustments are available to install on an electric guitar?

Comment: Depends on the component value. With no numbers, anything could happen. On one extreme end, nothing might happen of the component has no effect on sound frequencies, on the other extreme end, no sound will be heard because it does not pass audio frequencies. Usually you don't put variable caps or inductors over pickup coils though, as there are better ways already to achieve tone adjustment. Can you be more specific with the question or describe why you ask this?

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to conventional tone pots which have a strongly damping effect on the pickup's resonance, switching various parallel caps preserve a strong resonant peak and and in general more versatile to achieve different sounds, than the tone pot.

However, to get what you need needs a lot of hearing, simulation and testing usually. Suitable value ranges depend a lot on what you are after and on the specs of the existing pickups.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feK0q9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Personally, I have modified guitar sounds a lot using switched RCL circuits. However, nowadays if you run guitars via software amplifiers, you get an infinite amount of EQ and effect tools for free. So this is rarely needed. The only thing you want to avoid is pickups that remove too much of the highend natively, because this is hard to restore if it's strongly attenuated in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In the most general sense a series capacitor will tend to attenuate low frequencies while a parallel capacitor will attenuate high frequencies.  For inductors it’s the other way round.  However, as @tobalt has said there will be other colouration of the overall sound in ways that are difficult to describe objectively.